# LandXML to Topography.ByPoints doesn´t work as expected

Tags: python, xml, revit-api, revit, topography

I´m new here, so I hope this thread doesn´t exist already.

I exported a LandXML file from Civil3D. In this file are 3 surfaces listed. Now my aim is to import it in revit and convert it to a topography. It was no problem to extract all the points and faces and generate a mesh. But with the Topography.ByPoint node I get a topography which doesn´t look right.

[mesh and topography][1]

I've already tried a lot. But now I have no idea what goes wrong. Does somebody has an idea?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented and documented a Revit add-in to import a LandXML surface to Revit back in 2010; maybe that will help?

http://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2010/01/import-landxml-surface.html

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I have used your LandXML-file in my dynamo project. And it seems to work. So I think my exported LandXML file seems to be incorrect. Can you tell me how or with which program do you have created the file?

Comment: that sample file was provided by a developer, so i do not know its source. you could check here: http://landxml.org/... however, also note that wikipedia says: LandXML: a non-proprietary standard for data exchange among the land development, civil engineering and surveying communities. The Open Geospatial Consortium (OGC) Land and Infrastructure Standards Working Group (LandInfraSWG) developed a UML as-is conceptual model of LandXML-1.2 that revealed problems with LandXML and broad disparity with the OGC standards baseline... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_markup_languages#L